# Convert enum array with set of nested enums to Map

Tags: java, java-stream

Cannot understand how to compose `Map<InternalErrorCode, ExternalErrorCode>` variable from  the following enum structure using Stream API:

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum ExternalErrorCode {

    // Internal error codes won't be duplicated across any ExternalErrorCode enums
    ERROR1(Set.of(InternalErrorCode.FOO, InternalErrorCode.BAR)),
    ERROR2(Set.of(InternalErrorCode.ZOO)),
    ...;

    // Expected output should be: [{"FOO","ERROR1"}, {"BAR","ERROR1"}, {"ZOO","ERROR2"}]
    private static final Map<InternalErrorCode, ExternalErrorCode> LOOKUP_BY_ERROR_CODE = Stream.of(ExternalErrorCode.values())
                                                                                           .filter(not(externalErrorCode -> externalErrorCode.getErrorCode().isEmpty()))
                                                                                           .collect(groupingBy(...)); // Here is unclarity

    private final        Set<InternalErrorCode>                            errorCode;

}
```

Can someone assist with it?

Comment: You’re better off with a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of the lookup `LOOKUP_BY_ERROR_CODE` can use a Stream with `flatMap` which expands all combinations of known `InternalErrorCode` to `ExternalErrorCode` mappings. There is no need to check for empty sets as these will just be mapped as an empty stream, and finally the collector assembles the entries as a Map:

```
private static final Map<InternalErrorCode, ExternalErrorCode> LOOKUP_BY_ERROR_CODE
    = Stream.of(ExternalErrorCode.values())
            .flatMap(e -> e.errorCode.stream().map(i -> Map.entry(i, e)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

=>

LOOKUP_BY_ERROR_CODE={ZOO=ERROR2, BAR=ERROR1, FOO=ERROR1}
```

The above code will detect if there is duplicate mappings from internal to external - this gets reported by `Collectors.toMap` as:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException Duplicate key XXX
```